# Crash and Received memory warning

Tags: ios, swift3

I have below for loop to download files from server to my iPad 3 device. 
Running hundred of files, I got error and app crash. The console shown me "Received memory warning. Same logic running on my iPad Air was passed. Anyone can adivse how to resolve the problem.

iPad 3 -> iOS 9.3.5
iPad Air -> iOS 10.3.3

```
func download() {
        for (index, subJson): (String, JSON) in serverJson! {

            for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in subJson {
                    let filepath = subJson["path"].stringValue
                    let nUpdated = subJson["updated"].stringValue

                    if let oUpdated = localJson?[index].array?.filter({ $0["path"].string == filepath}).first?["updated"].stringValue {
                        if (oUpdated == nUpdated)
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                                self.progressView.progress = Float(self.count) / Float(self.totalCount)
                            }

                            count += 1

                            continue
                        }
                    }


                    var absPath = filepath

                    let strIdx = absPath.index(absPath.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)


                    if (absPath.hasPrefix("./"))
                    {
                        absPath = absPath.substring(from: strIdx)
                    }


                    let sourceUrl = URL(string: self.sourceUrl.appending(absPath))


                    do {
                        let fileData = try NSData(contentsOf: sourceUrl!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
                        try writeFileToLocal(absPath, fileData)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                        self.progressView.progress = Float(self.count) / Float(self.totalCount)
                    }

                    //print("Path: \(absPath)")
                    //print("%: \(Float(count) / Float(totalCount))")

                    count += 1

                }

        }


        do {
            // Remove temp json file first if exists.
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: oldManifestPath) {
                try? fileManager.removeItem(atPath: oldManifestPath)
            }

            // Write temp json file to local.
            try data?.write(to: oldManifestUrl)

            self.defaults.set(hashes, forKey: "LastHash")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.progressView.isHidden = true
            self.changeViewProperties(2)
        }

    }

}
private func writeFileToLocal(_ url:String, _ data:NSData) throws {

        let url = URL(string: url)
        let path = url?.deletingLastPathComponent().relativePath
        let file = url?.lastPathComponent

        let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
        let filePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(path!)


            var isDir: ObjCBool = false
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (filePath?.path)!, isDirectory:&isDir) {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: filePath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            FileManager.default.changeCurrentDirectoryPath((filePath?.path)!)
            try data.write(toFile: file!, options: .atomicWrite)
            print("Update: \(filePath!), \(file!)")

        FileManager.default.changeCurrentDirectoryPath(documentsPath.path!)
    }
```

Then I call the function "download" in DispatchQueue.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.downloadFiles()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory waring is occuring as you are processing hundreds of Things on main thread just a Trick that you can try out if it helps you take that function in background queue instead of main Queue , you may get some ui warnings which you need to manage as updating ui in background thread

I do not know if it will help you or not but you an just give it a try for once

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
    {
        //BackGround Queue Update
        self.downloadFiles()

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                //Main Queue Update With All UI

        }
}
```

as background thread is always good to manage huge processing for example kingfisher library take data on main thread and return on main thread but process it in background thread